# Is there any way to update my .html file if i have used funtion names and parameters in .js file which will be mixed to 'a, b, c,d..'?

Tags: javascript, html, compression, mixins

I want to compress and mix my js code, but i find i have used some function and parameter in my html file and they will not work if i mix the names in js file.

Here is the js code in the begining:

```
function Add(str1, str2)
{
    var strSum = str1 + str2;
    return strSum;
}
var sum = Add(1,2);
```

I compress and mix the code by uglifyjs:

```
function n(n,r){return n+r}var r=n(1,2);
```

I used 'Add' and 'sum' in my html file:

```
var val = Add(2,3);
document.getElementById('BOX1').innerHTML = val;
document.getElementById('BOX2').innerHTML = sum;
```

Do i have to change 'Add' and 'sum' to 'n' and 'r'? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Check the docs about usign mangle [here](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#the-simple-way)

Comment: For this to work correctly, you should put *all* the Javascript code in the Javascript file. Best not to put inline Javascript in the HTML in most cases, *especially* if you're using a minifier

Answer (score 0):

An Identifier(Variable or Function name) do not change when you compress or minify your javascript code. Try minifying your code using [javascript-minifier](https://javascript-minifier.com/) or [JSCompresser](https://jscompress.com/). I have tried them and they will not change the function names of your code.

Comment: Thank you, i worked out how to mix the parameters and remain the function names. but 'try to change function names' is one of the demand and i have no idea about it=.=